# Format partial functions like match functions in Scala with IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, code-formatting

IntelliJ (14.0.3, Scala plugin 1.4) formats regular case/match blocks after a function as so (this is from some HTTP code):

```
get("/work") { x => x match {
  case (200, result) => ...
  case _ => ...
}
             } // I'm not worried about this brace
```

If I collapse that obvious `x => x match`, it formats it like this:

```
get("/work") {
               case (200, result) => ...
               case _ => ...
             }
```

That kind of formatting gets messy if the call to `get("/work")` uses a longer url (as I have in places). It gets even worse if I have further nested things.

Is there any way to make IntelliJ format the case statements to be indented by one tabstop relative to the original statement, instead of relative to the opening brace?

Comment: This is the first time I am seeing this... My Idea works just fine... probably I am lucky... :)

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ + Scala plugin are you using ?

Comment: IntelliJ 14.0.3, Scala plugin 1.4

Comment: It happens to me all the time when I pass partial functions to other functions, eg when `map`ing and `filter`ing

Comment: I am using IntelliJ 14.0.3 and Scala Plugin 1.3.3, may be 1.4 has some bug. `Note to self` - DO NOT upgrade Scala plugin.

Comment: I'll give 1.3.3 a go and see what happens; pretty sure it's been around since last year at least though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it's a matter of setting the right code-style options.

In Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Scala, Wrapping and Braces -> Method call arguments, `Do not align block expression parameters` must be on, if `Align when multiline` is on.